# Are employers allowed to create their own tags?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

I've seen a [job ad](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-foveated-rendering) and one of the skills described there was a tag which I haven't recognized, namely *foveated-rendering*.

However, when I went to the tags on SO, there seems not to be anything like that in the list.

Am I missing something or is it possible to put in custom tags related to a specific assignment of an employer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, employers are the ones that decide which tags get assigned to a job, and they can create the ones they want to use if they don't exist yet.

In this particular case, it seems to be related to [a technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foveated_rendering) used in video games, and even if it's not a tag on SO, there are [3 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foveated+rendering) about it.